# access denied for user debian-sys-maint

Tags: mysql, debian, admin

I have had problem with mysql. I tried to execute this:

```
echo "show databases" | mysql -B -N
```

But I got:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But when I exec:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

I got an 'OK'.

I did

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO debian-sys-maint@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'your password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where password is from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. But it didn't help. (of course I flushed priv and restarted mysql).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is, your `GRANT` statement uses `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD` clause, and in this case mysql expect to get a *hashed* password, not a plaintext one.

Use `IDENTIFIED BY 'your password'` instead, if you wish to supply a plaintext password.

Answer (score 126):

That’s because Debian has a MySQL account `debian-sys-maint` used for switching on/off and checking status. The password for that user should be the same as stored in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. The file looks like this:

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = <password>
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = <password>
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

If the password doesn't match (for example because you changed it manually) the init script won't work anymore. You should set the password according to the file. So

```
mysql -u root -p
# Then type MySQL root password
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Comment: I have fields [client] and [mysql_upgrade] in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf. Passwords are the same in the file and in database for user.

Comment: Yes, all you need - update password, because this pass is unique for each installation.

For example: you move data_dir from one server to another, so the pass doesn't match

Comment: This does not work anymore with MySQL 8. I used ALTER USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';

Answer (score 3):

Most easy way to restoring the debian-sys-maint user, is to reconfigure package mysql-server-5.5. That if you know the password for the root user of MySQL, you can try to restore the user and its password in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

NOTE: if you cannot stop mysql pid, just run `sudo killall mysqld`. This is needed for reconfiguring the mysql-server-5.5.

Comment: @specializt. It solve my problem. Be careful about the above notation.

Comment: Why should i be "careful" about some "notation"? That doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Because if before running the command, the mysql service not stop, maybe the command can't execute on some tables in mysql.

Comment: this results in `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.7 is broken or not fully installed`