# PhpMyadmin error 1045 on digitalocean server

Tags: wordpress, server, phpmyadmin

can anyone help I was installing PHPMyAdmin on my digitalocean WordPress server by using the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring` then I choose apache and did yes yes then I got this error :- [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnRw.png)

then I tried so many things but can't solve it I have seen some other StackOverflow thread [access denied for user debian-sys-maint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644300/access-denied-for-user-debian-sys-maint) tried all nothing worked can anybody please help me m new

Comment: Did you find a solution? same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading my version of Linux Mint. The upgrade uninstalled phpmyadmin and when I reinstalled it I got the same error.

I eventually figured out it was a password mismatch between what was in the config file and what the database user was using. This is how I fixed it:

Find the password in the config file:

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

You will see something like:

> user     = debian-sys-maint 
> password = QOLla97eGTZmNWVp

Once you get the password, change it in the database, then restart mysql:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
$ (enter root password)
mysql> ALTER USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'QOLla97eGTZmNWVp';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

After this my phpmyadmin installs successfully. Hope this helps someone.